# android-Sqlcipher - cant insert a new row to database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

this is my code :

```
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
    File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("db");
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "Ab61", null);
    database.execSQL("drop table comments");
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,spot_id INTEGER,server_id INTEGER" +
            ",description TEXT,uid TEXT ,dates TEXT,name TEXT)");

    database.execSQL("insert into comments values (null, 34, 3, 'asdasd', 'asdsad', 'asda', 'asds');");
    Cursor ss=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from comments", null);
    Log.v("this",Integer.toString(ss.getCount()));
```

I've db database ,it's an sqlite database . this is a test code so , I remove the whole database ,create it again and insert a new row .

It doesn't get any error .

the cursor getCount return 0 , it means there is nothing added to database  .
It driving me crazy :(

could you help me ?

Comment: You are inserting **"NULL"** for a *PRIMARY KEY* value **_id**

Comment: @NetStarter This is perfectly fine for an autoincrementing column such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the data into a different database (`database`) than that which you are querying (`db`).

Comment: is it answer just blindly saying db or databse ........this is already has been explained in the question itself SQLiteDatabase db,this not at all considered as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private void InitializeSQLCipher(){
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(getApplicationContext());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("demo.db");
        databaseFile.mkdirs();
        databaseFile.delete();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "test123", null);
        database.execSQL("create table t1(a, b)");
        database.execSQL("insert into t1(a, b) values(?, ?)", new Object[]{"one for the money","two for the show"});
}
Cursor c = null;
c = database.rawQuery("SELECT a,b from t1", null);
if (c != null){
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            //Log.e("xlcx", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("a")));
            Log.d("xlcx", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("b")));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

please refer

http://androidjug.blogspot.in/2014/07/sqlcipher-for-android-application.html

Comment: did u run it or not, if u have any problem to get an error ,tell me

Comment: This is just a blob of code that uses a different database and does something different. Especially without any explanation, this is not useful for answering the question.

Comment: what else great explanation u want ,do have the set up for sqlcipher i mean using SlitOpenHeler ,then what i haven the is code for using inside the activity, ask me if have any confusion rather than saying blind comment